# How to make a shop visible in google map with lesser zoom?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I added a shop into google map a year ago , it showing fine and coming on suggestion on search too, but the problem is when we explore that area without search by zooming into it , [image]the name of the shop comes very late , when other small shops names are appearing before it , 
So my question is, Is there any trick or something by which the name can appear with in a very high altitude , (something similar like SEO for google) ??

Comment: Do you have a website where you embed Google Maps?  Or are you asking if we can make this shop more visible for maps.google.com?  On your own site you can do this; I'm not sure what you expect we can do about maps.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, @Chanky, but it's one for marketing or SEO consultants, not developers. It would need widespread testing across many variables (or more Googling) to find out if the algorithm for Google's SERPs (Search Engine Ranking Pages) and similarly Maps.Google.com, shows geo-targeted results in tandem with whatever the users query was (including business place names).

Verifying a Google+ page and a YouTube account through a Gmail and activating Google Webmaster Tools meta tag on your site couldn't hurt though.

//EDIT:
My last remark there was in jest, but seriously, that's a great place to start if, as you mentioned, "other smaller shop names are appearing before [you]."
Should this question get closed, then dm bobbyfritze online.